# Figuring out quantiles in quantile regression

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, prior, quantiles, quantile-regression

Suppose I have a dataset $\{y_i,x_i\}$ $i=1,2,...n$. For the response variable, $y_i$ as per quantile regression I have the following likelihood:

$$p(y_i|\beta,\alpha_i,\sigma) =\frac{\alpha_i(1-\alpha_i)}{\sigma}\exp\left(-\frac{\epsilon_i(\alpha_i-I(\epsilon_i<0))}{\sigma}\right)  $$

where, $\epsilon_i=y_i-\beta^Tx_i$, and $\alpha_i$ is the percentile. This is an asymmetric laplacian.

Usually for a synthetic dataset you can generate the data and know what the $\alpha_i$'s are (because you generated them).

1. Question is for a real dataset how would you know what the $\alpha_i$ is. My first thought was to put a uniform prior on $\alpha_i$ and look at the posterior, however this would symmetricise the likelihood (atleast intuitively it does). Is ML an option? This would highly depend on $\beta$ which in turn would depend on $\alpha_i$'s.
2. If above estimation of $\alpha_i$ is not possible what datasets would give you the quantile directly (with corresponding $\alpha_i$).

Comment: Shouldn't $\alpha_i$ be a single, known and fixed probability between 0 and 1 (like 0.5 if you are modelling the median)? (I am referring to intuition and also to http://dx.doi.org/10.4236/ojs.2012.25068)

Comment: Sure. If I was modeling the median. But how would you know what the median observations are. From a Bayesian perspective You don't have to restrict yourself to modeling just the median.